# Get files from directory by dynamic path

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get files from a directory, and I have the directory's path in my configuration file. If I get files names like this:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"SomePath", "*.*",
  SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

So all work perfect. But if I try to get fileNames like this:

```
var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("Key");
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path[0], "*.*",
  SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

I get an empty list. I think the problem is in the syntax of @ before the string path. But how can I give the @ before the path into the string path[0]?

Thanks.

Comment: path[0] must not contain any files.  @ only applies to string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more on [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx). These are denoted with a leading @ sign followed with the string within double quotes, where the string does not need escape sequence for special characters. For example `@"c:\Docs\Source"` is same as `"c:\\Docs\\Source"`

In your case make sure `path[0]` is in `"c:\\Docs\\Source"` format

Comment: my full path is : D:\PlatinumGalleryOleg\Oleg\StatusWeb\Content\Upload it work for Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\PlatinumGalleryOleg\Oleg\StatusWeb\Content\Upload") but not work for var path = "D:\PlatinumGalleryOleg\Oleg\StatusWeb\Content\Upload" , Directory.GetFiles(path)

Comment: replace '\' with '\\' so that your path is like 'D:\\PlatinumGalleryOleg\\Oleg\\StatusWeb\\Content\\Upload' so you won't need the leading @

Answer (score 0):

You can add a backslash before an existing one:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path[0].Replace("\\", "\\\\"), "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```